# Embed PDF to shiny app

Tags: r, pdf, download, shiny, filepath

I don't really know where to begin with this - I have a file that is akin to an appendix that I want made available to my shiny app users. Is possible to embed a PDF from my local drive in to my shiny app & if so is there an ability to have the pdf icon built in? Meaning when you click the pdf icon, you'd download the file specified in the code.

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have a pdf icon file `pdficon.png` and a pdf file `mypdf.pdf`, put them in the subfolder `www`. Then in your app:

library(shiny)

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$a(tags$img(src="pdficon.png"), href="mypdf.pdf", download="pdfname.pdf")   
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Then clicking on the icon will download the pdf file under the new name `pdfname.pdf`.